Is there a way to limit the amount of disk space used by VSCode Dev Containers?
I program on Windows using VSCode, WSL2, and the Dev Containers extension. This morning I had about 16GB of free space on my hard drive, but after opening one of my folders in a container in VSCode, I had less than 1MB of hard drive space.
When I look resource usage in Docker Desktop, I see that "Container memory usage" is around 1 GB / 22.88 GB. I think 22.88 GB is way more than I need for development, and I'm wondering if I can limit that in some way.
Does anyone know of a way to limit the amount of disk space used by dev containers?
I've been clearing out unused images, volumes, and build caches via Docker Desktop, and I also have run Powershell commands to shrink my VHDX file. Even after that, I'm still having space issues, so I wanted to see if reducing the disk usage by the dev containers was an option.
Thanks!
